# Compare Guid with default or empty?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the right way to check whether a Guid is empty?

First method:

```
Guid value;
// ...
if (value != Guid.Empty)
```

or second method:

```
if (value != default(Guid))
```

I think the second method is better, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Well... what are you trying to check for?

Comment: second example gives you `Use of unassigned local variable 'value'`

Comment: `default(Guid) == Guid.Empty`

Comment: If the guid is not always relevant, perhaps having a nullable guid would make more sense?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `Guid.Empty == default(Guid)` it does not really matter, but I would prefer `Guid.Empty` for readability.

Comment: I would argue that both are fine from a readability point of view, it really comes down to what the check actually means. Checking whether the record is in a default state is different than checking whether it contains an empty value (IMO).

Answer (score 9):

`Guid.Empty` is equivalent to `new Guid()`, which is also equivalent to `default(Guid)`.

When you decompile [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) structure, it seems;

```
public static readonly Guid Empty = new Guid();
```

---

Since `Guid` is a `struct`, from *[Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx)*;

> The value produced by setting all value-type fields to their default
>   values and all reference-type fields to null.

Since field types of `Guid` are, `short`, `int`, `byte`, (and this types default value is `0`), when we use `default(Guid)` we get a `Guid` with all fields are `0`.

From [`Guid.Empty Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty.aspx)

> A read-only instance of the Guid structure **whose value is all zeros**.

When we write this code;

```
Console.WriteLine(default(Guid));
Console.WriteLine(new Guid());
```

outputs;

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

If you care about readability (which I think you should) `Guid.Empty` seems better to me.

Comment: This is the most unnecessary explanation I have ever made `:)`

Answer (score 5):

The both are the same!

`Guid.Empty` is a readonly field of Guid, having the value `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`.

With `default(Guid)` the compile creates a constant value, having `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`.

In both cases your value is compared to another value somewhere in memory.

Use `Guid.Empty` for readability.
Use `default(T)` when you are working with generics.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the second purely because you have the record in an *uninitialized* state, therefore, it will contain the *default* value. You are checking whether the variable is in a default state, not whether it's empty - 2 different checks (IMO).

`Guid.Empty` is the equivalent to `default(Guid)` in .NET so from a technical point of view it doesn't matter, however, comparing to `Guid.Empty` gives me the impression that your checking for a particular value, not whether the record is in a default state.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following:

```
var guidIsEmpty = value == Guid.Empty;
```

Both are *technically* correct, however, comparing to Guid.Empty definately makes for more-readable code.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use `Guid.Empty` for readability. The only time I really use `default` like this is when there are no other options, for example when checking a `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but just wanted to chime in:

When defining a default value for a Guid as a parameter to a method, you will have to use default(Guid) rather than Guid.Empty, as Guid.Empty is not considered a compile-time constant.

This will compile:

```
private void MyMethod(Guid id = default(Guid))
```

This won't compile:

```
private void MyMethod(Guid id = Guid.Empty)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mekuri, but that doesn't directly answer the question. Your post is great as a Comment, but doesn't contain enough information to be an Answer in terms of SO.

Comment: This should be flagged as an error in the compiler.
The compiler should know that they result in the same value from the same constant.
Guid.Empty just takes a small detour and the compiler should know this. same for string.Empty and others like it.